# Why mp4 is not ALWAYS ! playing in ie 8 while using jw player?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jwplayer

I am working on a jw player plug-in, which plays videos from specified links from youtube and amazone s3. Youtube videos are working fine on chrome, firefox and IE. But videos from amazone  is not working in IE 8 (working fine in chrome and firefox). Then I tried direct link like "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/exxxxx/xxxxxxxxx.mp4", and found that some of the (mp4) files are playing and some not.   Why is it so? Can some one please help me to solve this out?

Console error shown on IE 8:
LOG: Error playing media: [object MediaError]
LOG: CAPTIONS([object object])

Here is the code:

jwplayer('myElement').setup({
            width:"100%",
            height: height,
            stretching: "fill",

```
                file: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/exxxxx/xxxxxxxxx.mp4"
```

});

Comment: Great, glad you got it!